# Can Paint.NET plug-ins be used outside of Paint.NET?

Tags: c#, imaging, paint.net

Can I **easily** use plug-ins made for [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET) in my own C# application (assuming that I comply with the plug-in licensing)?

My goal is to automate certain effects and it seems that there are quite a few for Paint.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Paint.NET was previously open source. I did a little Googling and I found the last open source version over here: http://d.freewareshare.net/938276

What you can do is take code from Paint.NET and use it in your project (eg. the stuff that plugins interface with). I believe Paint.NET 3.36 is licensed under some kind of super permissive open license, so even if your code is commercial in nature it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **any** .NET assembly, you can use it in your code as long as you use it correctly.

In your case:

1- Are you sure you will implement all the interface with the plug-in correctly (your code will behave as if it is Paint.NET)?

2- Are you sure the plug-in does not depend on Paint.NET itself in doing its job?

3- Are you sure all pubic interfaces of the plug-in does not depend on each other (I mean you need not to call 2 public methods consecutively to perform a single functionality)?

> If this plug-in is not
>   [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code), you can reverse its
>   code with [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx) and play with
>   the code as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your response Samesh.  I'm mainly looking for the "easily" part (i.e. can I just pass a bitmap to one of the plug-ins).  So far it looks like I would need to implement a "surface" object.